# how to send a email body part through MIMEMultipart

Tags: python, email

I am just curious to know if MIMEMultipart has any attribute in it where I can pass my email body part ... Only part I have come up with is

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = emailfrom
msg["To"] = emailto
msg["Subject"] = "hi find the attached file"
msg.preamble = "please PFA"
```

Is there anything like

```
 msg["Body"] = I will add a string or a text file
```

I googled for it and found

```
body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
body.attach(MIMEText(text))
```

but it's not working in my case.

And one more thing - how does `MIMEMultipart('alternative')` work? What functionality does it provide?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works for me:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'], msg['To'], msg['Subject'] = ... # specify your sender, receiver, subject attributes
body = 'This is the body of the email.'
body = MIMEText(body) # convert the body to a MIME compatible string
msg.attach(body) # attach it to your main message
```

You attach the `body` to the `msg`, and `body` in your case should be the `MIMEText` object.

Comment: While this technically works, there is no reason to wrap a single body part in a multipart container.

Comment: can i change a body content dynamically when needed    suppose i will make variable  body = input('message body:')  and then pass it to body = MIMEText(body)...

Comment: Yeah, body could easily come from any source, as long as you apply `MIMEText` to it and then attach it to `msg`.

Answer (score 18):

The purpose of a multipart container is to contain other MIME parts.  If you only have one part, by definition it's not multipart.

`multipart/alternative` is useful when you have the same content in different renderings.  A common case is to have the message body in both `text/plain` (no fonts, colors, images, or other "rich" content) and `text/html`.  Typically, the user will have configured their client to prefer one over the other, and so it will then display whatever the user prefers.  Somewhat less commonly, the user has a client which can display one type and not the other, so then it's a matter of technical necessity, not user preference, to display the supported version.

`multipart/related` is useful when you have multiple parts constituting a message.  For example, the `text/html` part in the `multipart/alternative` might want to pull in images which are supplied as "related" parts.  So a common structure in fact is

```
multipart/alternative
    +---- text/plain
    +---- multipart/related
              +---- text/html
              +---- image/png
              +---- image/png
```

or even another `multipart/related` above that if there is an attachment which is independent of the `multipart/alternative` renderings.

For your concrete example, just declare the body part as `text/plain` instead:

```
msg = MIMEText(text)
msg["From"] = emailfrom
msg["To"] = emailto
msg["Subject"] = "hi find the attached file"
```

For what it's worth, you should normally not need to mess with the MIME preamble, or imagine that a client will display it. (There will only be a preamble when there are multiple parts.)

If you do have an actual attachment you want to include, then this:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = emailfrom
msg["To"] = emailto
msg["Subject"] = "hi find the attached file"
msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
attachment.set_payload(data)
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Comment: so to send multiple attachments what should i do?

Comment: Once you have a multipart container, you can add as many new parts to that as you like. It's not uncommon to have a text part and multiple related parts of other types.

Comment: With Python 3.6+ the new `EmailMessage` API makes these things slightly easier. Nothing here really goes beyond what's in the standard Python [`email`: Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) documentation, so I'll just defer to that for what to use in the 2020s.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise to just use some email package that does not "bother" you with knowing anything about types.

Introducing [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (I'm the developer).

It will automatically do what you want (attachments, images, html code, fall back and many other features).

```
pip install yagmail
```

then

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('myemail', 'mypass')
mixed_contents = ['some text', '/path/to/local/img', '/path/to/mp3', 
                  '<h1>a big header text</h1>']
yag.send('toaddr@email.com', 'subject', mixed_contents)
```

You will end up with some text, some header, inline image and an attached file.